question orders "Newest" and "Active" working strangely
Next Day: this is happening across  stackexchange and is a bug, see
"Newest Questions" tab showing last active user instead of the asker
In case it matters:  I'm on a desktop, running Linux, I use   browsers Firefox  and Chrome. Appears to me same behavior for both browsers.
I guess I  can post  screenshots. Until a few days ago, when I chose to look at the questions on Main  under the "Newest"  order, it would show  them in the order asked, and the lower right corner  would show the time "asked."
I noticed yesterday, it is now mingling in questions showing when and who "modified,"  indeed one "answered."  So this is closer to the way the "Active"  order had worked. Now the Active order does some other thing.
Note, 12:25 Pacific:  it is possible that "Newest"  is still showing the questions strictly by time asked,  but then  putting information by most recent modification.
This first image is the screen capture   from the global Meta post:




That seems to have changed on all sites, so it is probably better asked at https://meta.stackexchange.com

@MartinR Now there is post about this issue also on [meta.se]: "Newest Questions" tab showing last active user instead of the asker.
